# Google Analytics gtag enhanced ecommerce add to cart event not recognizing product information

Tags: javascript, jquery, enhanced-ecommerce, gtag.js

I am implementing Enhanced Ecommerce on a site and i am having issues with inserting the product data into the gtag event. Also the site is using version 1.11.2 of jQuery and i can't update from this.

This code has been live for about 5 days on the site and when i use Firefox and Google Analytics Debugger it looks like everything should work, but when i console.log or print the response to a div the product info is not displayed.

When i `console.log(cartProducts);` it logs the array as expected

```
   {
     id: "WC091119", 
     name: "Workers' Compensation Section Meeting", 
     category: "EVENT", 
     price: 0.00, 
     quantity: 1
   }
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // Search transaction products. Add each project to an Object. Then add each Object in to an array

    const cmbaordertable = document.querySelector("[id*='ShoppingCart_ItemGrid'] tbody");
    const cmbaordertablelength = document.querySelector("[id*='ShoppingCart_ItemGrid'] tbody").rows.length;

    const cartProducts = []

    for (i = 0; i < cmbaordertablelength; i++) {
        const productSku = cmbaordertable.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML.split("-")[1];
        const productCat = cmbaordertable.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML.split("-")[0];
        const productNameHTML = cmbaordertable.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
        const productName = productNameHTML.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
        const productPrice = Number(cmbaordertable.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
        const productQuantity = Number(cmbaordertable.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);

        // cartProducts.push(transactionName);

        const cartProduct = {
            id: productSku,
            name: productName,
            category: productCat,
            price: productPrice,
            quantity: productQuantity
        };
        cartProducts.push(cartProduct);
    }

    gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
        "items": [
            cartProducts          
        ]
    });
});
```

This is what i receive from the console

```
Executing Google Analytics commands. analytics.js:16:359
Running command: ga("gtag_UA_9915896_1.require", "ec", "ec.js") analytics.js:16:359
Running command: ga("gtag_UA_9915896_1.ec:addProduct", [{id: "REAL092619", name: "Real Estate Law Section Lunch Meeting &amp; Guest Presentation", category: "EVENT", price: 0, quantity: 1}]) analytics.js:16:359
Running command: ga("gtag_UA_9915896_1.ec:setAction", "add", undefined) analytics.js:16:359
Running command: ga("gtag_UA_9915896_1.send", "event", {forceSSL: true, &gtm: "2ou9b0", hitCallback: [function], eventCategory: "ecommerce", eventAction: "add_to_cart"})
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I did it using below code once. Please see the below code whether It helps you.

```
              for (var i = 0; i < vm.orderItems.length; i++) {
                  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
                  'id': resp.orderId,       // Transaction ID. Required.
                  'name': vm.orderItems[i].itemName,  // Product name. Required.
                  'sku': '0',  // SKU/code.
                  'category': vm.orderItems[i].itemParentCategoryName, // Category or variation.
                  'price': vm.orderItems[i].itemPrice,// Unit price.
                  'quantity': vm.orderItems[i].itemQuantity // Quantity.
                });
                 ga('ecommerce:send');
              }
```